# Flex: which event is fired as soon as user enters a number in datagrid column?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a datagrid in which some columns are editable. I have 3 colums available_quantity, sales_quantity and return_quantity out of which sales_quantity and return_quantity editable. What i want is once the user enters sales_quantity and return_quantity  and if there total is greater than available_quantity it should immediately display the alert. I wrote keyup event to handle this..

```
protected function dataGrid_keyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            var avail_qty:int=parseInt(dataGrid.selectedItem.available_qty);
            var return_qty:int=parseInt(dataGrid.selectedItem.return_qty);
            var sales_qty:int=parseInt(dataGrid.selectedItem.sales_qty);
            var total:int=return_qty + sales_qty;
            if(total>avail_qty)
             Alert.show("hi");
        }
```

but the problem is first time when i edit the value sales_quantity and return_quantity it does not show me alert even there total is greater than available_quantity.
If i click any one of the column again and press backspace then it shows me "hi" in alert.
which event should b used to handle this. Keypressed event is not available in datagrid

Answer (score 2):

How about the help pages of the DataGrid ?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/DataGrid.html#eventSummary   ???

I would listen for this event "itemEditEnd" :)

---

**UPDATE - Spark DataGrid**

See following event description from flex manual.

```
gridItemEditorSessionCancel
Dispatched after the item editor has been closed without saving its data.   

gridItemEditorSessionSave
Dispatched after the data in item editor has been saved into the data provider and the editor has been closed.  

gridItemEditorSessionStart
Dispatched immediately after an item editor has been opened.    

gridItemEditorSessionStarting
Dispatched when a new item editor session has been requested.
```

Comment: But i have spark datagrid. The event u mentioned is for mx. What is eqivalent for spark.

Comment: @user1419919 Pleas read the flex manual. It's the fastest way to learn and find answers to your questions. Please check the updated field.